# Click a listbox item and display textfile text in labels

Tags: c#, label, text-files

I'm getting stuck clicking a listbox item (the items in my listbox is .txt files in a folder) and displaying the values in the .txt file.
the values in the .txt files are all seperated with a "," and I want each Split item to display in labels on my form.
my file path is: System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "data"
my .txt file names are the names of the selected item in my listbox.

I have a basic idea of what should happen, but I have no clue how to express this in code.
My Code:

```
private void custList_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        string foldr = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "data";
        string file = custList.SelectedIndex.ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with your text file. As you mentioned, it contains *values*. C#, being a versatile & mature language has a lot of functions,methods,classes pre-built to help boost your programming experience. Such a method is [ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext), a part of the `File` class. In the simplest words, this method opens a text file, reads it, returns it's value. A sample use of this method could be :

```
string TextFromFile = File.ReadAllText(File_Path_Goes_Here);
```

Moving on... Your *text file* has multiple values *separated by comma(,)*. In such cases, each value needs to read as a separate value upon retrieving or displaying. So, you want a `List` of the values, end of story. In C#, you have a wide range of [generic lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) to use from. As the *values* in the text file are simple strings, you can use a `List<string>` in this regard. A basic usage example of `List<string>` would be :

```
List<string> TestList1 = new List<string>();
TestList1.Add("First Value"); TestList1.Add("Second Value");

///or
List<string> TestList1 = new List<string>(){ "First Value", "Second Value" };
```

In your particular case, `File.ReadAllLines` is worth an example. The method opens a text file, reads it, closes it. Of course it returns the value read from the text file, as an array. So, when passing values to the generic list, you can simply make use of this method. Example :

```
 ...... new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(Path_Of_File_Goes_Here));
```

The only twist here is that the *values in your text file are in a line(maybe)* and also *are separated by comma*. So, what do you think should work here ? `ReadAllText` or `ReadAllLines` ? I will leave it upto you.

Once values are read from the file, we can make use of the `Split` function to split the values upon each occurrence of a comma(,). A simple example :

```
List<string> NameList = "Josh,Riley".Split(',').ToList<string>();
```

And last but not the least, the headline of the question which doesn't seem to have anything to do with the post itself, here's what you can take a look at :

[Control Click Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.click)

[ListBox.GetItemText](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ListControl_GetItemText_System_Object_)

**Tip:** The `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox` class returns or sets the selected item of a listbox.

Comment: Thank you. This is not a homework thing. I'm creating software to ease my workload, but since programming has never before interested me as it does now, I'm enjoying it. I changed my text file set-up a bit to have better control, and now record all the info in one text file. I will try and apply your knowledge, and will get back to you with my results. My file is now just over 1900 lines long with many show and hide controls and calculators and stuff, so thanx for the input, I enjoy learning this stuff and i"m sure i'll read your post 100 times before I succeed, keep you "looped".

Comment: "So you cannot just pass a single value to it when declaring it." But you can `List<String> lst = new List<string>() { "Mary" };`

Comment: @Mary , Yeah, well, not sure how i missed out on that. Maybe didn't cross my mind. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you want to show the values of your text file, so I will just provide you what you need to retrieve those informations.

To get values from your file:

```
public string[] GetValues()
{
    string[] values;
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(foldr, file))
    {
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        values = text.Split(',');
    }
    return values;
}
```

Then you can show them using an array:

```
public void Main()
{
    string[] values = GetValues();
    foreach(var value in values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: nope, its giving me a error on the public string[] GetValues, it states that; "not all code paths return a value" and then all my code is marked red.

Comment: Weird, I tested it out before posting the code.. Are you sure you closed all brackets? If you can post what you did so far (Editing your post).

Comment: I ended up solving it with the info Zack provided, thanx. I do however have a problem of the files duplicating in my listbox, but I think a if statement can fix that?